# Extract cropped parts of image into separate images using OPENCV

Tags: opencv, crop

How can I extract EACH crop into seperate image using C++ ? (My Opencv version 2.4.10)

[image]

I've filtered the contours to match desired size width/height ratio of a License plate. (third image - Rectangles 3)

Now I need to extract all found candidates into "i" seperate images that will have the same size as the "i" candidate, so I can segment the characters and use OCR algorithm.

The desired output from this image will be:

Two images each containing cropped version 
(ideally extracted with some extra added width/height as is shown in the image)
 of the found bounding box.

[image]

It's questionable to me, if I need seperate images or I can simply work with the whole image containing just the cropped parts (and black background as in shown images) in order to segment characters.

I'm providing part of my code here:

```
    findContours(crop, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE,
            CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

    vector<Point2f> ContArea(contours.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
        approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true);
        boundRect[i] = boundingRect(Mat(contours_poly[i]));

    }

    // Draw polygonal contour + filled bonding rects

    Mat drawing4 = Mat::zeros(src_gray.size(), CV_8UC3);

    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
        Scalar color = Scalar(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255),
                rng.uniform(0, 255));

        rectangle(drawing4, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), color,
                CV_FILLED, 1, 0);

    }

    imshow("Rectangles4", drawing4);

    float ratio;
    Mat drawing3 = Mat::zeros(crop.size(), CV_8UC3);

    // Draw bonding rects

        for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
        Scalar color = Scalar(0, 255, 0);

        double a = contourArea(contours[i]);

        ratio = (float) boundRect[i].width / (float) boundRect[i].height;

        //check for min, max size of area and its ratios

        if ((a > 200 && a < 2600) && ((ratio >= 1.3) && (ratio <= 10))) {
            printf("a: %f ratios: %f", a, ratio);

        //drawContours(drawing3, contours_poly, (int) i, color, 1, 8,
                    vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point());
       rectangle(drawing3, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), color,
                        CV_FILLED, 1, 0);
        }
    }

    imshow("Rectangles3", drawing3);
```

Comment: For each bounding box: `Mat cropped_image_i(original_image(bbox))`, or for deep copy: `Mat cropped_image_i = original_image(bbox).clone()`

Comment: This seems to work lovely! Thanks alot!

The only problem is in showing image the next crop seems to overlap the last crop.

Is it because I'm showing it as this?

imshow("crops",crops[j]);

Tested, it overlaps only in showing the image as such in imshow

I'm gonna add an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Miki for providing the answer!

The cropping is shown in the edited part of the code

```
    float ratio;
    int j=0;
    Mat crops[10];
    Mat drawing3 = Mat::zeros(crop.size(), CV_8UC3);

    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        Scalar color = Scalar(0,255,0);

        double a = contourArea(contours[i]);
           ratio = (float)boundRect[i].width/(float)boundRect[i].height;
                    if ((a > 200 && a < 2600)&&((ratio>=1.3)&&(ratio<=10))){
            printf(" a: %f ratios: %f image%d",a,ratio,i);

            drawContours(drawing3, contours_poly, (int)i, color, 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point());
            rectangle(drawing3, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), color,
                            CV_FILLED, 1, 0);

            Mat cropx(src_resized(boundRect[i]));
            crops[j]=cropx;

            imshow("crops",crops[0]);
            if (j==1) imshow("crops1",crops[1]);
            j++;
            waitKey(0);

        }
    }
        imshow("Rectangles3", drawing3);
```

Basicaly just few more lines of code

```
//outside the loop
    int j=0;
            Mat crops[10];


//inside the loop    
    Mat cropx(src_resized(boundRect[i]));
                    crops[j]=cropx;
        j++;
```

The result (not resized to larger area yet) is shown here: 
[image: Crops]

To enlarge, just use (or similar attributes, this needs more testing)

```
boundRect[i].x=boundRect[i].x -boundRect[i].width/4;
boundRect[i].y=boundRect[i].y -boundRect[i].height/4;
boundRect[i].width=boundRect[i].width +boundRect[i].width/2;
boundRect[i].height=boundRect[i].height +boundRect[i].height/2;
```

Enlarged results can be seen here:
[image]